# html/jade warnings when using i18n library with jade in a meteor project

Tags: meteor, internationalization, pug, spacebars, meteor-helper

I am using the following meteor template code in Jade to display a dropdown however I am receiving the following warnings.

Is this the correct way to implement the i18n internationalization package or is there an alternate accepted way to remove the warnings?

Assuming this is the correct implementation is there a way to either suppress the warnings or configure the parser to expect this as valid code?

```
# HTML version - header.html
<template name="i18nTest">
  {{> i18n_dropdown}}
  <div>{{_ "company"}}</div>
  <div>{{_ "business"}}</div>
</template>


# Jade version - header.jade
template(name='i18nTestJade')
    span
      +i18n_dropdown
    span
      {{_ "company"}}
      {{_ "business"}}


Warning: missing space before text for line 5 of jade file "client/layouts/i18nTest.jade"
Warning: missing space before text for line 6 of jade file "client/layouts/i18nTest.jade"
```

For clarification, I previously posted only the HTML version by mistake. I have now updated the example with the Jade version. Also, both versions are working however I get console warnings.

Comment: HTML isn't valid Jade, for the most part. Try: `template(name="i18nTest") {{> i18n_dropdown}}` (next line) `div {{_ "company"}}` (next line)  `div {{_ "business"}}`. Though the code looks i18n syntax looks iffy as well, may want to re-read the docs for that. Actually, might want to re-read the Jade docs as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nuclearman for the feedback. I mistakenly only posted the html version earlier.

Comment: Ah I see. It's still rather odd. The docs use `[[[ ]]]` rather than `{{ }}`, though perhaps that's unrelated. The underscores `_` seems iffy as well (why? and are you sure there needs to be a space there). In any case, looks like there's a spacing issue in `{{_ "company"}}` and `{{_ "business"}}`. It could also be an issue with `+i18n_dropdown` I tried it using the Jade online demo, and it worked fine on that front but I didn't have the mixin. Perhaps your Jade needs updating? Could also be that i18n isn't setup right. I'd remove the second span temporally and see what happens.

Comment: @Nuclearman many thanks. Changing the brackets helped. I still get a warning but the code works. I need to spend a bit more time on it.